# C# Data Structure to allow fast finding of objects in a large dataset with a property between two given doubles

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I have a list of large number of objects of the following form:

```
public class Point
{
    public double X {get; set;}
    public double Y {get; set;}
    public double Z {get; set;}
    public double DistanceFromStart {get; set;}
}

List<Point> points = GetPointList();
```

In a given calculation I can narrow down the ones to consider to within a range of DistanceFromStart. So DistanceFromStart is effectively an index. I know I will repeatedly call code similar to this:

```
points.Where(p => p.DistanceFromStart < lowestDistance &&
 p.DistanceFromStart > highestDistance).someothercals
```

hundreds of times.

DistanceFromStart is not necessarily unique so not sure how I would use a dictionary and I thought about ToLookup and Lookup but that seems to be for specific values, rather than a range of doubles. What is going to be the most efficient way to use DistanceFromStart in a similar way to an index for best performance?

Comment: Just sort it by the property? Then these objects will be continuous in memory.

Comment: LINQ doesn't know your assumptions about data, so `Where` will always be `O(n)` where `n` is List length.

Comment: Dictionary<double, List<Point>>

Comment: @Ewan: "...DistanceFromStart is not necessarily unique..."

Comment: How often do the contents of the List change?

Comment: @Spo1ler - but say I have 50000 points in the list, and DistanceFromStart could narrow that down to 10 points, there must be a better way than looking at all 50000 and doing it like a database could?

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt The List won't change, once we have it we are doing lots of calculations on the same set of data

Comment: Okay. Then keeping the list sorted is not much overhead, and performing binary searches would already be a big improvement.

Comment: Going back to @Ewan's suggestion actually he says List<Point> - when i first build the dataset the majority of the values here would be a list of 1 point - but in the rare case of duplicates that list would have two points - so we could use dictionary and do we think that would be faster than binary search?

Comment: @willem, hence Dictionary<double, _LIST_<Point>>

Comment: @Ewan: And what double functions as the key?

Comment: yes will be much faster, but you obvs have to consider the time spent building the dictionary up and converting it back to a list later (maybe .GroupBy and SelectMany)

Comment: @Willem DistanceFromStart, when you get duplicated the Value is a list of 2 or more Points

Comment: @Ewan: Aaaaaaaaah, sorry, it didn't register, wasn't reading properly.

Comment: although its likely that it would be more performant to use a range of values as the grouping as Tim suggests in his answer (although nto sure about the lookup mehtod)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with Ewan's suggestion in the comments to use a dictionary but of the form

```
Dictionary<double, _LIST_<Point>>
```

The idea is that when building up the dictionary initially if the DistanceFromStart is already in the dictionary then you add to the point list of that entry. When going through the dictionary to find results you then just handle a list of points rather than a single point.

Tim's answer could well be quicker, however, it would have need much more thought to implement. In this instance using the dictionary that Ewan suggested gave seamless calculations to the end user so the extra complication for any speed improvements associated with Tim's answer were not required.

Answer (score 1):

I think using lookup is going to be your best bet. If you need to use it for ranges you could pretty easily add another property that was a distanceFromStart copy with reduced resolution. For example, round to the nearest ten and store based on that value.

So if the distance is 5, maybe it has another index property of 0 that indicates it is in the 0-9 range. Another with a distance of 11 would use 10 because it was 10-19.

Using this technique you should be able to effectively index your results, and by adjusting the sizes of the indexes you should be able to tune the algorithm.

Note that you do not have to actually store the value to use it as the key, however doing so may prove more performent than doing the calculation repeatedly. Again, as always measure before micro-optimizing like that.